# How hibernate is managing synchronization of data between Object and Table..?

Tags: java, hibernate

Consider the following scenario,

how the synchronization is working ?

I have a table Employee,

```
E_ID(PK)     E_NAME
----         ------
001          Ramu
```

I have a EmployeeBen POJO class representing the above table,

I created 3 objects for EmployeeBean class, i.e emp1, emp2, emp3

I am using these objects in the application in different places.

Now I updated name by using emp1 object (`emp1.setName("Raju")`),

will this new value reflect on other objects or not ..?

if the new values reflects on other objects, how it is reflecting (without using `session.refresh(emp2)` or `session.flush()`)..?

I want to know , How hibernate is managing synchronization concept..?

Comment: It doesn't is the simple answer. Hibernate guarantees that the same object in the database with be `.equals` in the application but not that they will be `==`. You must either use `session.refresh` or manage synchronization yourself. Long lived sessions are discouraged at any rate.

Comment: Show some code. We don't know how you created these 3 onjects, in which session, if the session is closed or not, etc.

Comment: all objetcs are created using different session

Comment: Then they're completely independant of each other, and won't be refreshed automatically. Why don't you test it by yourself?

Comment: it is a question faced in interview..